# Elasticsearch get results count of other indices with same query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, searchkick

I have a cluster setup with multiple indicies, generated from a rails server. Each index is a model in my server.

Looking to search a single index, but get counts for the other indices (models) based on my query json. Is this possible?

The query im using is generated from [searchkick](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick) and quite large so I'm refraining from posting here. I'm trying to figure out if `aggs` does what I need, something like. I'd like to refrain from doing a 2nd query *if possible*

```
POST blog_index/_search
{ 
  "query": { ... }
  "aggs": {
    "results_count": { ... }
  }
}
=> What I would like to receive
{
  "aggregations": {
    "results_count": {
      "blogs": 123,
      "users": 234,
    }
  }
}
```

Example:
If do a `{ "term": { "type": "funny" } }` on `blog_index/_search`, and there are 3 users with that `type`, I'd like to get that count as part of my `blog_index` query

Comment: are you trying to query an indices and use the result to query another indices? the question is not clear. please use an example of dataset.

Comment: I'm trying to get a result count from another index based on the query I have currently. 

lets say i'm doing a `match_all` on `blog_index` and there are 3 users in my `user_index`, I'd like to find out how many users there are (3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: You can aggregate on field `_index`.

```
"group_by_index": {
  "terms": {
    "field": "_index",
    "size": "30"
  }
}
```